# Verifying a method call in a base class that takes a delegate parameter using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delegates, mocking, moq

I am trying to test that a method is called, and that method exists in a base class of the class under test.

When I run the below example with a simple string parameter it works but when there is a delegate parameter the test fails.

I created the below sample to demonstrate the problem.  If you take out the delegate parameter in `SomeMethod` and in the test, the test will pass.

#### Failing Code:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod(string someString, Func<bool> function)
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        SomeMethod("foo", () => true);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var test = new Mock<DerivedClass>();
        test.Object.DoSomething();
        test.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod("foo", () => true), Times.AtLeastOnce);
    }
}
```

#### Passing Code:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod(string someString)
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        SomeMethod("foo");
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var test = new Mock<DerivedClass>();
        test.Object.DoSomething();
        test.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod("foo"), Times.AtLeastOnce);
    }
}
```

Error message for failing test:

```
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.SomeMethod("foo", () => True)
No setups configured.

Performed invocations:
BaseClass.SomeMethod("foo", System.Func1[System.Boolean])`
```

Whole error message:

```
Test method UnitTestProject1.Tests.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.SomeMethod("foo", () => True)
No setups configured.

Performed invocations:
BaseClass.SomeMethod("foo", System.Func`1[System.Boolean])
   at Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(MethodCall expected, IEnumerable`1 setups, IEnumerable`1 actualCalls, Expression expression, Times times, Int32 callCount)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
   at Moq.Mock.Verify(Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Times times)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Func`1 times)
   at UnitTestProject1.Tests.TestMethod1() in UnitTest1.cs: line 16
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I change the test to following it passes. See I changed `() => true` to `It.IsAny<Func<bool>>()` which means it can be called with any Func. Do you care if its `() => true`?

```
var test = new Mock<DerivedClass>();
test.Object.DoSomething();
test.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod("foo", It.IsAny<Func<bool>>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

Comment: Thank you. The example was just a trivial example to demonstrate the problem.  Your answer inspired the fix for the real problem. I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer yet.

Comment: @will The reason this answer is correct, is that two delegates `Func<bool> d1 = () => true;` and `Func<bool> d2 = () => true;` need not compare equal, i.e. `d1.Equals(d2)` can return `false`. See [`Equals` method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ts3c5tx.aspx) for an explanation that the target method (and target instance for non-static methods) must be the same. However `()=>true` might create a *new* "real" method even if another `()=>true` exists already elsewhere. Here, the two lambdas are even in different classes. And one is inside an expression tree.